# How do i merge Multiple WHERE in SQL (STUCK)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

How do i merge this 2 data together to get data like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw3qe.png)

```
SELECT A.schlvl AS School, COUNT(DISTINCT A.name) AS NoOfChild ,SUM(B.cat_id=1) AS Picture 
FROM child AS A INNER JOIN
question AS B 
ON A.child_id=B.child_id
WHERE B.answer=0 AND B.cat_id=1
GROUP BY A.schlvl


SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.name) AS Gotitright ,SUM(B.cat_id=2) AS Letters
FROM child AS A INNER JOIN
question AS B 
ON A.child_id=B.child_id
WHERE B.answer = 0 AND B.cat_id = 2
GROUP BY A.schlvl
```

OR

Something like this, but i am stuck with this

```
SELECT A.schlvl AS School, COUNT(DISTINCT A.name WHERE B.answer=0 AND B.cat_id=1) AS Picture , COUNT(DISTINCT A.name WHERE B.answer=0 AND B.cat_id=2) AS Letters
FROM child AS A INNER JOIN
question AS B 
ON A.child_id=B.child_id
GROUP BY A.schlvl
```

Comment: I would suggest , you should use **union** keywords for get results for two tables data together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query.

You can try to use `IN` in `B.cat_id` to get `cat_id` `1` or `2` in `WHERE` clause.

use *Aggregate function condition* let `CASE WHEN` in `SUM` function.

```
SELECT A.schlvl AS School, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.cat_id = 1 THEN A.name END) AS NoOfChild ,SUM(CASE WHEN B.cat_id IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) AS Picture 
FROM 
child AS A INNER JOIN question AS B ON A.child_id=B.child_id
WHERE B.answer=0 AND B.cat_id= in (1,2)
GROUP BY A.schlvl
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, how do i change this  `COUNT(DISTINCT A.name CASE WHEN B.cat_id IN (1) THEN 1 END) AS NoOfChild` to Distinct the number of student name who got it incorrect `B.answer=0` in any category

Comment: @Yongs I edit my answer `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.cat_id = 1 THEN A.name END)` you can try to use.